# Meta Tag scale and css media query

Tags: css, media-queries, meta, responsiveness

To view the site correctly as it should, I am using `initial-scale 0.3`.

Its okay for the content, but I want my header image a bit bigger.
I am using a css media query but it doesn't work.
With (meta)  `initial-scale 1` my queries are getting fired so I think I have to reconsider this.

Do I have to calculate the header image separately with factor 3 to fit in 0.3 scale?

If I set the css media query to 320 min width, nothing happens. 
What is the trick?

Comment: I can't think of a reason to use `initial-scale 0.3`. Something must be really funky if you're having to do that. I think you're *simulating* responsiveness by doing that rather than actually changing properties.

Comment: It makes sense to be honest. I have a bunch of thumbs and with 0.3 there are 3 per row without resizing Them. Its really enough and its what i need. I could do media queries for evry div but why not ging this way and adjust just the header IMG?

Comment: Okay, if i would do it this way, it doesnt fit the concept of media queries. Nevermind :)